# Issue in parsing a BufferedReader object

Tags: java, json, parsing

I need to read the output of a BufferedReader object which is in json format, parse the json and extract some values. My code looks as below:

```
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(proc1.getInputStream()));
        Stream<String> s = reader.lines();
        Object[] t = s.toArray();
        String result = Arrays.toString(t);
        JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray jArr = (JSONArray) jp.parse(result);
        System.out.println(jArr);
```

The JSONArray jArr looks as below:

```
[
  {
    "result": {
      "totalSize": 1,
      "records": [
        {
          "Owner_Name": "User Group",
          "Creation_Date": "2020-12-15",
          "attributes": {
            "type": "Case",
            "url": "http://google.com"
          },
          "Version_Number": 0
        }
      ],
      "done": true
    },
    "status": 0
  }
]
```

I need to get the properties of "records". I have the subsequent code working, just need to create a json object with the values inside "records". Output json object required is:

```
{"records": [
        {
          "Owner_Name": "User Group",
          "Creation_Date": "2020-12-15",
          "attributes": {
            "type": "Case",
            "url": "http://google.com"
          },
          "Version_Number": 0
        }
```

I am facing json array and json object incompatibility issues while trying to case jArr as json object. Can someone suggest a way to do this

Comment: Why are you reading the contents as a `Stream`? What do you think `Arrays.toString(t);` does? Just read it (or join the `Stream`) as a single `String` and then parse that.

Comment: If you looked at the output of `Arrays.toString(t)` you would immediately see the problem.

Comment: I have no problem in Arrays.toString(t);..I am able to parse result string and store it in json array jArr. Its just that I need to extract the properties under "record" from the jArr

Comment: Also joining the steam using stream.collect(Collectors.joining() is fetching null

Answer (score 0):

Join the stream as a single String. Use try-with-resources so the BufferedReader gets closed.

```
String result;
try (Stream<String> stream = reader.lines()) {
    result = stream.collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Comment: I get result as null on doing this